# How to become educated about the permiting/contracting process for a panel replacement in rural Pennsylvania?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, meter

We had a cabin built by a general contractor in the 1960’s that still has the original 200 amp panel. We’re looking to have the panel replaced.  Its located inside the house.  Recently, the utility company replaced the original meter on the house with the ‘digital’ read out type. The new panel to be installed is going to be another 200 amp and so if I'm correct, the new meter won’t have to be changed

The interview process of finding a licensed electrician is going to be getting underway. The possible choices of finding an electrician from the 3 nearest towns in a 35-50 mile radius from the cabin have populations ranging between 5,200 to 9,300

Others besides us who vacation in this area share stories over many years of contractors just not wanting to work (or they’ll give a commitment to a job and then cancel out to never be heard from again). It wouldn’t be a surprise if an AHJ also took this same attitude and his good old time to show. Our primary residence is in one of the large populated cities of PA where we aren’t burdened by all of this

Trying to find contractors around there to do jobs is difficult when they just don’t want to get off their derrieres to do any work. The cabin is located in a remote place and the travel distance for an electrician to commit to driving there from a larger, more populated city doesn’t make for any of this easier

We’re finding it hard right now to get prepared with information.

Things we’re trying to gain knowledge on involving processes and inspection requirements are:

•   Are inspections required by power utility companies prior to this sort of job beginning?

•   When does an AHJ perform the inspection duties?

•   How is the AHJ chosen or who brings the AHJ in when the inspection needs to be done ?

•   If an AHJ learned after the replacement was completed and told us an un-licensed electrician completed the work, could he exercise his authority to make us hire someone to remove it ?

•   Can only a licensed electrician pull a permit ?

•   If an electrician candidate tells us to pull the permit ourselves, isn't that enough to arouse suspicion he's likely practicing without a license ?

•   Who’s the issuer of a permit for this type of job?   The local governing body of the municipality where the electrician is based out of ?

•   Isn’t it a requirement to have the meter pulled to disrupt power fed to the panel ?

•   Is pulling the meter the purpose of a permit for this type of work ?

•   Who can disconnect the residential power ?  Only licensed electricians ? Or only representatives from the power utility company ?

Finding a database for these 3 towns to verify whether any electricians we researched have valid licenses is wasteful time spent because these small towns don’t share the info online. Sure, we can ask candidates to bring along their license to show us. And I can probably make a pretty compelling photo-shopped document too, if I was an unscrupulous person in a small town and has always gotten away doing it without ever being challenged.

Comment: What is the reason for replacing the panel?  There are a couple known panels that must be replaced, but unless a panel is damaged, replacing with the same size might just be a waste.  If wanting to add more circuits, adding a sub panel might be a cheaper plan.  A picture of your panel, with inside pictures might be helpful.

Comment: We discussed this @crip659 on one of my older threads. The name ends with an O . .  as in Obsolete. That's not the only reason though. It needs replaced due to this brand's faulty breakers

Comment: Some other members may be able to offer insight if you reveal who your power provider at the cabin is, since different utilities have different policies. At this point in time you might be best-served to get an outside disconnect (as required in NEC2020) installed - that makes further work inside the house much easier, since you can shut the power off from outside (and so can the fire department.)

Comment: Your local building department will have all the information.  They are the ones to permit the work.  You can do most the work yourself.  Just need to have it inspected.  Some/most power companies will turn off your electricity for you(usually free once a year).

Comment: Penelec - First Energy

Comment: PA has a "state licensure lookup" page - but it doesn't appear to cover electricians, plumbers, contractors, etc... so it's useless for this. Oh, Well.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Do you mean to say that an outside disconnect is now required to be installed as per the NEC 2020 ?Doing this before a new panel replacement sounds crazy. What is advantage of having this if it woudn't be required though ? the meter pulled to disrupt the power is sufficient, is it not?  In reply to the PA state licensure lookup, I'm aware it's useless information

Comment: The advantage to installing it now during this disruptive work is that any future work which would usually require pulling the meter now only requires you to throw the disconnect. If you want to add solar, or consumption CTs on the main feeders, or a whole house generator, etc, etc ... it all just becomes one disconnect throw away and a short outage, rather then power out for long enough for the power company to visit twice.

Comment: It may or may not be required, but given you're doing a panel replacement, bringing that up to current code would not be an usual requirement as part of the panel replacement. It also makes your life simpler by removing the need to pull the meter, once it's in place.

Comment: @KMJ a generator would be nice to have. I can't think of other reasons though

Comment: County/city or town would help as well. For example, in MD (as of a year ago, it may have changed since then) some counties required a NEC 2020 disconnect and some did not.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact  I believe you're asking the address of the cabin. The County is Forest. Its not in any town, and neither is there a postal address. Its in the forest. Hence the name that the County was given

Comment: @manassehkatz I wasn't trying to sound like a smart alec. Its just that its in the middle of the forest where a logging trail was cut through from the oil exploration days in the 1800's

Comment: Don't want the address. That would not be a good idea. But County plus "not in a town" should be sufficient. No address? Really?

Comment: In this kind of situation, rather than trying to get to know things remotely or in theory, I'd take a short vacation in the area and observe the lay of the land/local society. Walk into the electrical company office, the permitting/inspection office, electrical contractors' offices, etc. Hang out in coffee shops/restaurants, library? Talk to lots of people, maybe have smaller pet project in mind to talk freely about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some *general* answers. But your mileage may vary:

- Are inspections required by power utility companies prior to this sort of job beginning?

Generally not. The inspection is *after* the project is done. An inspection before would be basically useless. Whether the *utility* actually requires an inspection of its own will depend on how much the utility does vs. AHJ.

- When does an AHJ perform the inspection duties?

Generally when the job is either totally done or very nearly done.

- How is the AHJ chosen or who brings the AHJ in when the inspection needs to be done?

The choice AHJ is out of your hands, in two ways. It is generally the county but sometimes city or town. It is what it is. But more than that, you don't get to choose Alice or Bob - you (or your electrician or contractor) schedules an inspection and the AHJ sends whichever inspector they want to send.

- If an AHJ learned after the replacement was completed and told us an un-licensed electrician completed the work, could he exercise his authority to make us hire someone to remove it?

In many places, yes. But in some places they may just inspect it and if everything was done properly then just make you pay whatever fees should have been paid and possibly a penalty fee.

- Can only a licensed electrician pull a permit?

Jurisdiction dependent. In some places, yes. In some places, a homeowner can get officially qualified through some paperwork/fees/exam and then pull their own permit (I know people who have done that in my area). In some places the homeowner can pull the permit as long as a licensed electrician is listed on it as doing the work.

- If an electrician candidate tells us to pull the permit ourselves, isn't that enough to arouse suspicion he's likely practicing without a license?

Jurisdiction dependent. But definitely not necessarily a problem. But a big advantage of the electrician pulling the permit is that they know how to fill out the paperwork correctly. Even then it can get complicated (my electrician had to talk to multiple people to figure out how to properly list a generator interlock because the paperwork didn't have a place for it, but he knew who to ask and what to ask).

- Who’s the issuer of a permit for this type of job? The local governing body of the municipality where the electrician is based out of?

Based on location of the property. Many electricians work in multiple cities, counties and even states, but the rules, permit, inspection, etc. all depend on the location of the property.

- Isn’t it a requirement to have the meter pulled to disrupt power fed to the panel?

Yes, for now. But new construction (and *possibly* panel replacements) in many jurisdictions now require installation of a disconnect at the meter. That is primarily, as I understand it, so that the fire department has an easy way to cut all power. But it *also* gives you a way to cut power to your main panel (which may technically be a subpanel, depending on configuration) without pulling the meter.

- Is pulling the meter the purpose of a permit for this type of work?

No. The primary purposes of the permits are (a) to make sure that things (electrical in this case, but also plumbing, construction, etc.) are done in a safe manner, compliant with appropriate codes and (b) revenue for the local jurisdiction. The revenue part is, I think, not actually that big a deal - by the time the jurisdiction pays for an inspector and running an office and processing paperwork and records storage, etc. I suspect that in many jurisdictions there really isn't much "profit" for the jurisdiction, but there can be some.

- Who can disconnect the residential power? Only licensed electricians? Or only representatives from the power utility company?

Technically, the utility. In reality, the utility may delegate to the electrician for disconnect, reconnect or both. Especially reconnect, because it is easy to schedule the disconnect for the start of the job, but it is not always so easy to predict the end of the job. At least in my area it is pretty much standard policy *when working with a licensed electrician* for the utility and electrician to agree that the electrician will put the meter back in when the job is done and then notify the utility to do any other necessary work (depending on the nature of the job, that could be new feeder, etc. or could be nothing at all).

But pulling the meter must *always* be coordinated with the utility, even if the utility says "Just cut the tag, pull it yourself and call us when you put it back" because otherwise they can claim that you messed around with the meter. The idea being that if they *know* you are pulling the meter then they can easily check before/after readings, etc. Less of an issue these days because with smart meters they aren't going a month between readings to know if someone is messing around with the meter.

Comment: Many thanks to you. This is knowledge that can be very very frustrating and difficult to research online by oneself and find the answers to. I can't tell you how much this helps us. We're going to be much better prepared.  Along with the comments that the others have also contributed to this thread, this is all everything I would've hoped for. Thanks to everyone of you. You're all awesome